# Using endpoints or HTTP requests

Tags: android, ios, google-app-engine

I've been playing around with the google app engine and went through the android tutorial.  It wasn't too bad but the iOS one is a little more troublesome, particularly when it comes to endpoints in XCode.

Anyway, I did manage to get through that but was wondering, what would be the harm in using the http URL that you can see in the API explorer?  You could build the query string in the iOS app and then handle the JSON response.

Would like some clarification on if that's not recommended and why
:)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If none of the features of endpoints really make you want to use it, then you probably shouldn't.

You can read about the features in the docs, but some that stuck out for me are that it makes user authentication easier, but only for Google accounts, it makes app authentication easier, and it generates client side copies of the server entities that you expose in your endpoints.

On the other hand, it adds a layer on top of HTTP, and there is no point in bothering with that extra (proprietary) layer if those don't hold real value for me.

In my case, I started using endpoints but am moving away from it.  I wish they would separate the code generation feature from endpoints because I think that would be quite useful if it were more general purpose.

Comment: Indeed authentication did seem easier with endpoints but it wasn't suitable for my needs.  Thanks for the answer, it clears things up well :)